# target HTML elements created dynamically with nested PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in HTML with nested PHP creating the same row (tr) a certain number of times anyways the tr elements have a td containing a submit button which is for delete that tr using Jquery .ajax() function well I don't get to target that tr to be removed in the AJAX response because all tr are identical same name same id attributes so all are deleted at once so how can I say to Jquery to target that specific tr?

```
<table>
    <?php 
    //some SQL code
    while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
    ?>   

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->data ?></td>
        <td><form method="get" class="deleteForm" action="delete.php"><input type='submit' id='delete' class="delete" value='Delete'></form></td>
    </tr>


    <?php
    endwhile; 
    ?>
</table>
```

Now on the AJAX response I'd like to do this:

```
$(".deleteForm").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

        //stuff...

        success: function(res)
            {
            $("my_Actual_tr").remove();
            }
        });     
    });
```

It would be something like: 'target and delete the tr in which the button clicked was in.

Comment: show the relevant html

Comment: If it's just a button inside a td inside a tr, your `element` is the button and you want that tr, then it's `element.parentNode.parentNode` without jQuery.

Comment: "all tr are identical same name **same id** attributes" ... [Ids should **always** be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), that is what makes them Ids. Remove the ID attribute if it's not needed, append an ID from your row data to the ID, e.g `id="delete_4568"` or Add a row index to ID e.g. `id="delete_2"`.

Comment: On a further note of HTML validity `form` is not a valid child of [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) or [`tbody`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

Comment: Thank you Jon P that's it. I assign the form an id equal to the id of the table from the database then the tr a class equal to the id as well now on the Ajax  request I can do var id = this.id and then $("." + id).remove()

Answer (score 3):

you could use something like

```
$(this).closest('.tr').remove()
```